# jQuery: Every 5 seconds, automatically click on next image in a list?

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, slideshow, setinterval

I have a given list of images, presented as thumbnails:

```
<ul id="thumbs">
    <li class="small-img"><img src="images/feature1.png" /></li>
    <li class="small-img"><img src="images/feature2.png" /></li>
    <li class="small-img"><img src="images/feature3.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

I use jQuery so that, when the user clicks on an image, it replaces the featured image in a div (which I got [from another StackOverflow Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612575/whats-the-best-jquery-click-a-thumbnail-and-change-the-main-image-module/7976356#7976356)):

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){
    $('div.feature-photo img').hide().attr('src',$(this).attr('src')).fadeIn();
});
```

My question is: Is there a way to make it into a slideshow? Maybe automatically "click" on the next picture every 5 seconds? Does `setInterval`  play a part in this? I'm trying to be really basic about it, and avoid using more plugins than I have to. (But if there is no other way, I will consider it..)

Would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2):

You may easily calculate the next image within the switch function.
This way you won't mess up your var space ;)

```
(function switchToImage(img) {
  $(img).click()
  var images = $('#thumbs img');
  var nextIndex = ($.inArray(images, img) + 1) % images.length;
  setTimeout(function() { 
    switchToImage(images[nextIndex]) 
  }, 5000);
})($('#thumbs img')[0]);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure ... what will happen with the first (the immediate) execution of the function? img will be undefined, won't it?

Comment: Yepp, it will, but that is not a problem. `$(img).click()` will simply do nothing, as there is no element to be clicked. The index of `img` will be `-1` thus the next index will be `0` and the procedure will switch to the first image after 5 seconds. So, yeah, it's somewhat a little laggy at start, as the second image will be shown after 10 seconds. But you could add `$('#thumbs img')[0]` as argument to the initial call.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the plain JQuery way, if you like.
Here's my try

```
var intervalId;
$(function(){


function cycleImage(){

    var onLastLi = $("#thumbs li:last").hasClass("current");       
    var currentImage = $("#thumbs li.current img");
    var targetImage = $('div.feature-photo img');             
    $(targetImage).hide().attr('src', $(currentImage).attr('src')).fadeIn();

    var currentLi = $("#thumbs li.current");
    currentLi.removeClass("current");

    if(onLastLi){
        $("#thumbs li:first").addClass("current");
    }else{        
        currentLi.next().addClass("current");
    }

};

 intervalID = setInterval(cycleImage, 5000);



})
```

And you can find it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/68964/2/)

Answer (score 0):

setInterval might be the answer to your question

```
var currImg = 0;
var $images;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $images = $('#thumbs img');
    changeImg();
    window.setInterval(function() {
        currImg++;
        if(currImg == $images.length) currImg = 0;
        changeImg();
    }, 5000);
});

function changeImg() {
    $('div.feature-photo img').hide().attr('src',$images.eq(currImg).attr('src')).fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to think in terms of what your *code* should do, not what the user does that triggers your code. So rather than "automatically 'click'", you just want your code to automatically show the next image.

So the first step is to move your code out of the `click` handler:

```
function showImage(img){
    $('div.feature-photo img').hide().attr('src',$(img).attr('src')).fadeIn();
}

$('#thumbs img').click(function() {
    showImage(this);
});
```

And then the question becomes: How do I call `showImage` every five seconds with the "next" image. Well, first we'll want to remember what the "current" image is. Easy enough to modify our `showImage` to do that:

```
var current = null;
function showImage(img){
    current = img;
    $('div.feature-photo img').hide().attr('src',$(img).attr('src')).fadeIn();
}
```

So then we just need a trigger to occur in five seconds. You *can* use `setInterval`, but I find it's really easy to have it get out of control, so I use a chained series of `setTimeout` instead, where each one sets up the next. And what would be a good trigger for that? Well, five seconds after the user clicks an image, so probably right there in `showImage`:

```
var current = null;
var timer = 0;
function showImage(img){
    current = img;
    $('div.feature-photo img').hide().attr('src',$(img).attr('src')).fadeIn();
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(nextImage, 5000);
}
```

Okay, so what should `nextImage` look like? I'd say we probably want to use `current`, perhaps:

```
function nextImage() {
    var $current;

    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }
    if (current) {
       $current = $(current);
       next = $current.nextAll("img")[0];
       if (!next) {
           $current.siblings("img")[0];
       }
       if (next) {
           showImage(next);
       }
    }
}
```

You might kick things off at the beginning by showing the first image:

```
showImage($("#thumbs img")[0]);
```

So bringing that all together, and making sure we wrap it in a scoping function so we don't create global symbols:

```
(function() {
    var current = null;
    var timer = 0;

    function showImage(img){
        current = img;
        $('div.feature-photo img').hide().attr('src',$(img).attr('src')).fadeIn();
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = setTimeout(nextImage, 5000);
    }

    function nextImage() {
        var $current;

        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = 0;
        }
        if (current) {
           $current = $(current);
           next = $current.nextAll("img")[0];
           if (!next) {
               $current.siblings("img")[0];
           }
           if (next) {
               showImage(next);
           }
        }
    }

    $('#thumbs img').click(function() {
        showImage(this);
    });
    showImage($("#thumbs img")[0]);

})();
```

(Or instead of a vanilla scoping function, you might use jQuery `ready`.)

The above is fairly rough, and completely untested, but you get the idea.

Answer (score -2):

You could use

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //trigger next picture}
,5000);
```

But you have to keeep in mind that if the user reloads the page, the Timeout starts from zero !