# how to stop jquery imageslider on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my website demo : http://daplonline.in/index5.php

i got this jquery from : http://designm.ag/tutorials/image-rotator-css-jquery/

i want to stop slider automatic to stop when user Mouse hover on Small thumb image current slide is automatic and user can't read image's advertise

i want to make automatic but when user click or mouse hover on small image slider must stop.

my jquery code is here

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var intervalId;
var slidetime = 2500; // milliseconds between automatic transitions

$(document).ready(function() {  

  // Comment out this line to disable auto-play
    intervalID = setInterval(cycleImage, slidetime);

    $(".main_image .desc").show(); // Show Banner
    $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0.85 }, 1 ); // Set Opacity

    // Click and Hover events for thumbnail list
    $(".image_thumb ul li:first").addClass('active'); 
    $(".image_thumb ul li").click(function(){ 
        // Set Variables
        var imgAlt = $(this).find('img').attr("alt"); //  Get Alt Tag of Image
        var imgTitle = $(this).find('a').attr("href"); // Get Main Image URL
        var imgDesc = $(this).find('.block').html();    //  Get HTML of block
        var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height();   // Calculate height of block    

        if ($(this).is(".active")) {  // If it's already active, then...
            return false; // Don't click through
        } else {
            // Animate the Teaser               
            $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0, marginBottom: -imgDescHeight }, 250 , function() {
                $(".main_image .block").html(imgDesc).animate({ opacity: 0.85,  marginBottom: "0" }, 250 );
                $(".main_image img").attr({ src: imgTitle , alt: imgAlt});
            });
        }

        $(".image_thumb ul li").removeClass('active'); // Remove class of 'active' on all lists
        $(this).addClass('active');  // add class of 'active' on this list only
        return false;

    }) .hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });

    // Toggle Teaser
    $("a.collapse").click(function(){
        $(".main_image .block").slideToggle();
        $("a.collapse").toggleClass("show");
    });

    // Function to autoplay cycling of images
    // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9259171/477958
    function cycleImage(){
    var onLastLi = $(".image_thumb ul li:last").hasClass("active");       
    var currentImage = $(".image_thumb ul li.active");


    if(onLastLi){
      var nextImage = $(".image_thumb ul li:first");
    } else {
      var nextImage = $(".image_thumb ul li.active").next();
    }

    $(currentImage).removeClass("active");
    $(nextImage).addClass("active");

        // Duplicate code for animation
        var imgAlt = $(nextImage).find('img').attr("alt");
        var imgTitle = $(nextImage).find('a').attr("href");
        var imgDesc = $(nextImage).find('.block').html();
        var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height();

        $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0, marginBottom: -imgDescHeight }, 250 , function() {
      $(".main_image .block").html(imgDesc).animate({ opacity: 0.85,    marginBottom: "0" }, 250 );
      $(".main_image img").attr({ src: imgTitle , alt: imgAlt});
        });
  };

});// Close Function
</script>
```

Comment: Dont you get anything in Google??? Try searching on Google first. M sure u will find the correct link

Comment: it's not solution i want to edit this code and stop slider when mouse hover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this,

```
$('.image_thumb ul li').on("mouseover",function(){
  clearInterval(intervalID);
});

$('.image_thumb ul li').on("mouseout",function(){
  intervalID = setInterval(cycleImage, slidetime);
});
```

add this at the end of your coding...

Answer (score 2):

Add this code at the end of your script.. I guess the mouse-over will pause the slider but i m not sure if the mouseout works or not.. Just give it a try and let me know about the result.

```
$('.main_image').on("mouseover",function(){
clearInterval(intervalID);
});

$('.main_image').on("mouseout",function(){
intervalID = setInterval(cycleImage, slidetime);
});
```

Adding the above lines will make the code as below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var intervalId;
var slidetime = 2500; // milliseconds between automatic transitions

$(document).ready(function() {  

  // Comment out this line to disable auto-play
    intervalID = setInterval(cycleImage, slidetime);

    $(".main_image .desc").show(); // Show Banner
    $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0.85 }, 1 ); // Set Opacity

    // Click and Hover events for thumbnail list
    $(".image_thumb ul li:first").addClass('active'); 
    $(".image_thumb ul li").click(function(){ 
        // Set Variables
        var imgAlt = $(this).find('img').attr("alt"); //  Get Alt Tag of Image
        var imgTitle = $(this).find('a').attr("href"); // Get Main Image URL
        var imgDesc = $(this).find('.block').html();    //  Get HTML of block
        var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height();   // Calculate height of block    

        if ($(this).is(".active")) {  // If it's already active, then...
            return false; // Don't click through
        } else {
            // Animate the Teaser               
            $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0, marginBottom: -imgDescHeight }, 250 , function() {
                $(".main_image .block").html(imgDesc).animate({ opacity: 0.85,  marginBottom: "0" }, 250 );
                $(".main_image img").attr({ src: imgTitle , alt: imgAlt});
            });
        }

        $(".image_thumb ul li").removeClass('active'); // Remove class of 'active' on all lists
        $(this).addClass('active');  // add class of 'active' on this list only
        return false;

    }) .hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });

    // Toggle Teaser
    $("a.collapse").click(function(){
        $(".main_image .block").slideToggle();
        $("a.collapse").toggleClass("show");
    });

    // Function to autoplay cycling of images
    // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9259171/477958
    function cycleImage(){
    var onLastLi = $(".image_thumb ul li:last").hasClass("active");       
    var currentImage = $(".image_thumb ul li.active");


    if(onLastLi){
      var nextImage = $(".image_thumb ul li:first");
    } else {
      var nextImage = $(".image_thumb ul li.active").next();
    }

    $(currentImage).removeClass("active");
    $(nextImage).addClass("active");

        // Duplicate code for animation
        var imgAlt = $(nextImage).find('img').attr("alt");
        var imgTitle = $(nextImage).find('a').attr("href");
        var imgDesc = $(nextImage).find('.block').html();
        var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height();

        $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0, marginBottom: -imgDescHeight }, 250 , function() {
      $(".main_image .block").html(imgDesc).animate({ opacity: 0.85,    marginBottom: "0" }, 250 );
      $(".main_image img").attr({ src: imgTitle , alt: imgAlt});
        });
  };

$('.main_image').on("mouseover",function(){
clearInterval(intervalID);
});

$('.main_image').on("mouseout",function(){
intervalID = setInterval(cycleImage, slidetime);
});


});// Close Function
</script>
```

Comment: Added but not working properly please check again :(

Comment: Actually, I think I didn't understand your question properly. Right now, your slider pauses when you hover over the slide!
Please make your question clear! :)

Comment: my question is solved :) i want to pause side when i mouse over on thumb (small) image left side....  it's solved by @CJ Ramki bay the way thank you for your time :) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "..." ) .mouseover(function() { 
     //Stop the animation here 
     $( "..." ).stop(); 
}).mouseout(function() { 
     //Do your animation here 
     $( "...").animate(); 
});
```

Comment: thanx for reply but where to put this line ? i can't find the mouseover function on this slider

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear the interval for image rotation:

```
$(function(){
var stop;
function rotate(){
 stop = setInterval(change, 1000);
}
rotate();
//Use the event you want to stop image rotation
$("#ok").click(function(){
 clearInterval(stop);
});
});
```

Comment: Thanx for avesome code but **where** to put this line ?? in jquery

Comment: Hi Vivek, just take care of "stop" variable scope, set it like "stop = setInterval(change, 1000);" in the events you want rotate to work.